# How to get product SKUs in onepageController without quote object?

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, onepage-checkout, product-list

I know product sku's can be fetched using the quote object and a foreach loop

```
foreach($this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item){
    $sku = $item->getSku();
    $_SKU = $item->getProduct()->getSku(); // or this way
}
```

but I want to know whether there is any other short and crisp way to do this?
I mean without using foreach loop, i.e. a inbuilt function returning an array of product data in the quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet returns array of quote items sku

```
$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getItemsCollection()->getColumnValues('sku');
```